# Gatling save html intput

Tags: gatling

I am getting an html response in gatling, containing an input with value.
I need to take that input value, store it and use it in the next request.

Can anyone help me to accomplish that, please?

Example of input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/tokenId4578swrtt" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture values from html responses by using css checks.

So, for your example on the request that returns the html page you would have:

```
.check(css("#__EVENTVALIDATION","value").saveAs("validationToken"))
```